# Why always something is running at port 5000 on my mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, tcp, process, port

I am a developer and I need to run my ruby app at port 5000, but always I try to run my app I get:

```
Address already in use - bind(2) (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
```

I know that the easiest way for solving this; is just change the port that I am using for running my app, but I want to know what happens, because every time I execute `lsof -i tcp:5000` and kill the process, automatically a new process starts running in that port.

I am using a macbook pro with MacOs Monterrey with version 12.0.1

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This happens because Control Center on Monterey listening to port 5000 and port 7000.

For fixing this you need to turn off `System Settings > General > AirDrop & Handoff > AirPlay Receiver`.

[More info](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682332)

Comment: I'm unsure exactly how long that would have taken me without this answer. Thank you, kind person.

Answer (score 0):

Goto **System Settings > General > AirPlay Receiver > Disable AirPlay Receiver option**.